# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, tabula, tabula-py

I was trying to read a PDF using tabula python package but I have received Unicode Decode Error. I tried using chardet to find encoding but it said None.

```
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate

df = read_pdf(open(r"C:\Users\rohit\Downloads\Capstone Data\\" + "CITY OF ROCHESTER.pdf",'rb'),pages="all") #address of pdf file
print(tabulate(df))



Got stderr: Oct 05, 2022 2:30:21 PM org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine operatorException
SEVERE: Cannot read JPEG2000 image: Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) Image I/O Tools are not installed

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [2], line 5
----> 5 df = read_pdf(open(r"C:\Users\rohit\Downloads\Capstone Data\\" + "CITY OF ROCHESTER, MINNESOTA - HEALTH CARE FACILITIES REVENUE BONDS, (MAYO CLINIC) SERIES 2022.pdf",'rb'),pages="all") #address of pdf file

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tabula\io.py:434, in read_pdf(input_path, output_format, encoding, java_options, pandas_options, multiple_tables, user_agent, use_raw_url, pages, guess, area, relative_area, lattice, stream, password, silent, columns, format, batch, output_path, options)
    432 fmt = tabula_options.format
    433 if fmt == "JSON":
--> 434     raw_json: List[Any] = json.loads(output.decode(encoding))
    435     if multiple_tables:
    436         return _extract_from(raw_json, pandas_options)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 1962: invalid start byte
```

Comment: are you sure the PDF is text based? There is a SEVERE error in there complaining about JAI tools not being installed. I don't think Tabula will work with image based pdfs out of the box without those tools. The pdf being image based would also explain the difficulty in finding the encodings.

Comment: @AllanElder What packages do you suggest?

Comment: Tough to say without the PDF - but the error message is suggesting JAI, which you can find here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/install-jai-imageio-1-0-01.html